# Do other vehicles or upgrades make a difference in Extreme Road Trip 2?

Tags: extreme-road-trip-2

I've been playing this game on my Android tablet the past few days, gathered a bunch of coins and in-game money. Also unlocking different vehicles and upgrading them too. **Does it matter if I buy a new vehicle or upgrade my existing one?**

I haven't noticed any difference in the way different vehicles perform, or if they have received upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

From what I noticed in-game, **different vehicles have different Hitboxes, Speed, and..."Turning Sensitivity"**...or however you would like to call those.
Some vehicles also have **different Centers of Mass.**

**Upgrading vehicles affect the "Turning Sensitivity".** Upgrading may also affect the Speed of vehicles but I haven't seen much of a difference anyways.